# convert a javascript object's value-field to array

Tags: javascript, object

suppose the object is `obj ={foo:"bla,bla2,bla3",bar:"bla,bla5"}`

I want to convert it to `'obj={foo:["bla","bla2","bla3"],bar:["bla","bla5"]}'`

Comment: One approach is `Array.map` over `Object.entries` using `String.split`— https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why you want to do that, but here you can just loop through `obj` with a `for...in` loop and split the strings by commas:

```js
const obj = {foo:"bla,bla2,bla3",bar:"bla,bla5"};
for (name in obj) {
  obj[name] = obj[name].split(',');
}
console.log(obj)
```